# How did Community approve this edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, community-user

I've used the "Edit" option for this [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14766001). However, due to an intermittent internet connection, my improved edit didn't go through and I received an unexpected error.

After that, I refreshed the page and saw that Community approved the edit.

[image: Image 1]

However, there isn't any other user who used the `Edit` or the `Reject and Edit` options, nor did the OP approve the edit.

So, how did Community approve it, seemingly at its own decision?

---

**Note:**

- For some reason, even though it showed that an unexpected error has occurred while submitting my improved edit, it's [actually saved](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41435686/2).
- This particular suggested edit does **not** show up in my review history.

---

AFAIK, the Community user only approves/rejects edits if the OP reviewed it or a reviewer used the `Edit` or `Reject and Edit` options:

> [image: Image 2]
>
> ---
>
> [image: Image 3]

Comment: I think the community also approves in case you choose "Improve edit". But then it appears in the edit history.

Comment: @Oriol Yea, but it will show my name too, as seen in the last screenshot

Comment: @Panda Maybe it just erred out this time. You _did_ say you received an error.

Comment: That edit doesn't actually appear in the revision history. I assume it was discarded as conflicting with yours.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if one uses "improve edit" and then cancel his own edit. Is the reviewed edit still approved? Might be what happend here.

Comment: @Tom No, pressing "Cancel" returns you back to the review menu, where it prompts you once again with all the actions ("Approve", "Reject", etc)

Comment: Possibly related? [How can the Community user review a Low Quality post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284134/242209)

Comment: @4castle Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think this happened because you edited over the suggestion.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/244695

> ## A user with full edit privileges saves an edit over yours
>
> If a user with full editing privileges for a post (including the original poster) begins editing the post at the same time as you, and they save their edit after you have already suggested it, then your suggested edit will be overridden in favor of their fully-privileged edit.

It looks like [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41435686/2) was virtually identical. It was probably auto-approved.

Comment: If that's the case then the post you link to needs updating because (unless I'm missing something) it indicates that the conflicting edit would be rejected in that case.